# How to pass multiple ng-templates to ng-content?

Tags: angular, swiper.js, ng-template, ng-content

I am using Swiper's swiper component and the way you can display slides is using ng templates with SwiperSlide directive on it. I want to make my swiper component reusable and use that component instead of swiper's component every single time. Heres how i want flow to be

Feature component -> passes multiple ng templates -> my swiper component then passes those ng templates to  -> Swiper's swiper component.

[image]